# How to call Pro*C Code from Java?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, oracle-pro-c

Currently I am working on a project where I need to migrate Oracle forms application to Java web application. There are some forms which calls Oracle Pro*C code for inserting and updating records to database.

I need to call the Pro*C code from Java. Please help me with some examples about how to call Pro*C code.

Answer (score 0):

The best option for you is having a Pro C wrapper application which calls Oracle Pro*C code for inserting and updating.

In your wrapper Pro C code you can take in command line arguments. Ex:-

```
WrapperProC Insert <Value1> <Value2> <Value3>
WrapperProC Update <SearchValue1> <SearchValue2> <UpdateValue1> <UpdateValue2>
```

And from within the Wrapper you can call the Oracle Pro*C code for inserting and updating, based on first (Insert/Update) Argument.

You can call the Wrapper from Java using Runtime.exec or ProcessBuilder.

**UPDATE:**

If you want more performance, you can make the Wrapper act as a Proxy Server with some socket programming and use your Java code as a client to connect to it with a socket and send in the command (Insert/Update)

Comment: Thank you for ur reply. U mean to say I should write a JNI wrapper around Pro C code and call it? I am new to this. That is why I have mentioned I need some working examples in order to understand how I need to proceed further.

Comment: Not a JNI Wrapper, A Pro C Wrapper.